# Copiar más de una lista a un csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

No termino de aclararme con el funcionamiento de `writerows`.

Tengo dos listas:

```
frases_1 = ['Tengo sueño','Come mucho','Abre la puerta']`
lista_1 = [8,3,6]
```

Estaba intentando copiar los elementos de ambas listas en un archivo csv de tal manera que quede así:

```
Texto;Número
Tengo sueño;8
Come mucho;3
Abre la puerta;6
```

Estaba intentando varias cosas pero no me sale. Por ejemplo:

```
with open("results.csv", 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='unix', delimiter=",",
                            quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        writer.writerow(['text-pros', 'total_points'])
        writer.writerows([frases_1] + [lista_1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`writerows` recibe un iterable en el que cada elemento es otro iterable que va a conformar la fila, cuando concatenas las dos listas lo que obtienes es:

```
[['Tengo sueño', 'Come mucho', 'Abre la puerta'], [8, 3, 6]]
```

Y deberías pasarle algo:

```
[['Tengo sueño', 8], ['Come mucho', 3], ['Abre la puerta', 6]]
```

Esto lo puedes conseguir usando [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), que retorna un iterador resultado de agregar los elementos con el mismo índice de cada uno de los iterables pasados como argumento:

```
import csv

frases_1 = ['Tengo sueño', 'Come mucho', 'Abre la puerta']
lista_1 = [8, 3, 6]

with open("results.csv", 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='unix', delimiter=",",
                        quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow(['Texto', 'Número'])
    writer.writerows(zip(frases_1,  lista_1))
```

Con lo que si que obtienes la salida deseada:

> Texto,Número
>   Tengo sueño,8
>   Come mucho,3
>   Abre la puerta,6